# Flex display - No wrapping on Android?

Tags: css

I'm displaying multiple DIV in a container and I want them to wrap when there's no more space on the right side. It's working fine on IOS, but I can't make it work on Android...

```
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M7yLn/457/

Thanks for help!
Bastien

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your fiddle seems to be that the children aren't actually being flexed. I've been experimenting heavily with flexbox recently, and concluded that `flex-wrap` isn't supported in Safari 7 (desktop or mobile), although Modernizr says it does support. I don't know whether you've tested in Android's built in browser or Chrome on Android, but it isn't unlikely that Android's built in browser doesn't support it (like mobile Safari doesn't).

However, the children in your fiddle aren't actually being laid out with flexbox, since you haven't set a `flex` CSS property on them. Another key to making flexed elements wrap is to specify either a `flex-basis` or a `min-width`, since `width` is overridden by `flex`. The two properties behave alike, but `min-width` is generally more predictable, whereas `flex-basis` will give you a base size of approximately what you specify.

I [forked your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zd7yspg/1) to show the elements wrapping according to `flex-wrap` (in supporting browsers). I tested in mobile Safari, where the layout indeed broke.